# Python Subprocess not printing vnstat process

Tags: python

Thank you for taking the time to read this post.

I'm trying to do live bandwidth monitoring in python using vnstat. Unfortunately, It is not printing the output that i want, and i cant seem to figure out why. This is my code below.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import time

def run(command):
 process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, shell=True ,universal_newlines=True)
 while True:
    line = process.stdout.readline().rstrip()
    print(line)



if __name__ == "__main__":
 run("sudo vnstat -l -i wlan1")
```

When i run this code in the terminal , this is the output i get :

```
sudo python testingLog.py
Monitoring wlan1...    (press CTRL-C to stop)
```

It does not show me the desired output when running "vnstat -l -i wlan1" in the terminal.

Desired Output :

```
Monitoring wlan1...    (press CTRL-C to stop)

rx:        0 kbit/s     0 p/s          tx:        0 kbit/s     0 p/s
```

What happens when i run vnstat -l -i wlan1 is that it will update it and be running live, so i suspect that my printing is wrong as it does not print the desired output but i cant seem to figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that your printing is wrong, it's the fact that `vnstat` keeps updating the same line without issuing a new line so `process.stdout.readline()` hangs at one point, waiting for a new line that never comes.

If you just want to redirect `vnstat` STDOUT to Python's STDOUT you can just pipe it, i.e.:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen(["vnstat", "-l", "-i", "wlan1"], stdout=sys.stdout)
while proc.poll() is None:  # loop until the process ends (kill vnstat to see the effect)
    time.sleep(1)  # wait a second...
print("\nProcess finished.")
```

If you want to capture the output and deal with it yourself, however,  you'll have to stream the `STDOUT` a character (or safe buffer) at the time to capture whatever `vnstat` publishes and then decide what to do with it. For example, to simulate the above piping but with you in the driver's seat you can do something like:

```
import subprocess
import sys

proc = subprocess.Popen(["vnstat", "-l", "-i", "wlan1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:  # a STDOUT read loop
    output = proc.stdout.read(1)  # grab one character from vnstat's STDOUT
    if output == "" and proc.poll() is not None:  # process finished, exit the loop
        break
    sys.stdout.write(output)  # write the output to Python's own STDOUT
    sys.stdout.flush()  # flush it...
    # of course, you can collect the output instead of printing it to the screen...
print("\nProcess finished.")
```

Comment: omg, Thank you so much, It works! I'm new to python so I didn't really know what the issue was or what was going on, and this really saved me. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi sir , so i've put in the code and it works but now i kind of need it to be in a string so i can keep sending it to a socket live, however it doesnt not let me change to a string and i get a really weird format when i try to print it.

Comment: @VictoryPhone - You should be able to send the `output` to any socket, you might need to encode it, tho. Either way, create a new question explaining the issue you're having including the _really weird format_ you get when trying to print the string so we can take a shot at what's behind it.

Comment: One simple alternative would be to give the vnstat command also the `--style 4` parameter which would result in new lines being used in the output.